# Coronal Mass Ejection and its effect on Earth's Orbit

Tags: magnetic-fields, solar-wind

Do CMEs (Coronal Mass Ejections) have an effect on Earth's Orbit around the sun? Given the the Earth and Sun are essentially two large magnets, one in orbit around the other. If so, how much of an impact is there?

Comment: The typical mass-scale of CMEs are $\sim10^{12}$ kg, about 18 orders of magnitude smaller than the sun (and 10 orders of magnitude smaller than the moon), so I would sincerely doubt that CMEs can do much of anything *gravitationally*, they still can really screw up global communications satellites & potentially cause nation-wide power-outages.

Answer (score 2):

Coronal Mass Ejections is just the sun releasing copious amounts of charged particles in a general direction at really high speed. I wouldn't think it would have any effect on the earth's orbit, because they don't have an effect on gravity.

It would be like throwing orange juice at a basketball. Nothing would happen apart from the basketball getting wet. I.e. the earth getting showered in radiated particles from the sun.

Also the sun and earth are kept in place by Gravity which is defined as the attraction between two physical bodies. Now if you consider the gravity of planets, stars, galaxies etc, they all experience strong gravitational effects. However for sub-atomic particles, they are not effected by gravity in the way large bodies are, they have their own attraction called the Strong & Weak Force, which is only subjected to the sub-atomic world.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No doubt the CME enhances momentarily the particle density of the magnetosphere resulting in a spike in the electric current and hence also a spike in magnetism that modulates slightly the geomagnetic field, however,a CME would not effectively modify the Earth's orbit.

Comment: Hi Ray, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that this community frowns on overt self-promotion; while it's not outright forbidden to link to your own website, you do need to make clear exactly how it supplements your answer, and don't make posts for the sole reason of promoting your site. I've removed the link since it didn't seem to be relevant to your answer here. If you want to expand on this answer, and you need to link to your site to offer further explanation, that's okay, but make sure it's very clear why you need to include that link.